# eclipse no autoinsertion for EPIC (Perl Plugin)

Tags: eclipse, perl, eclipse-plugin, epic

I want to use Eclipse to do my Perl programming. For this purpose I have installed the EPIC-Plugin.

But how do I get the EPIC plugin to automatically insert the templates? Or the shebang?
This is possible with Java-Class files out-of-the-box.
Why not with EPIC?
The templates that I talk about are the one under:
Window -> Preferences 
Perl EPIC -> Editor -> Templates

They don't seem to work at all.
For Java the work just fine
(almost same location - just replace "Perl Epic" with "Java")

EPIC Repo:
http://e-p-i-c.sourceforge.net/updates/testing

Comment: On a very unrelated note: try [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) (or the free version). I've tested EPIC for a short while and found it to be very unsatisfying when working with many projects, and lots of unrelated files as well. Komodo on the other hand has been a huge improvement because of its stability, speed and very simple to use built-in debugging. And it does have lots of templates (and snippets) out of the box ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I reluctantly will give it a chance...but all in all I think it should be possible with Eclipse and EPIC. I sort of want to have one IDE. And with Java my demands are met. So this should also work with EPIC.... somehow... because basicly this is the same "backend" - right?

Comment: OK Komodo seems to be completely Commercial => I don't want to use it. But thank you for the afford anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You should type the name of the template in the editor first - then hit ctrl+space, it should show you a list of all templates starting with that name.

So if you need a template to auto insert a shebang for example, have a template with these fields:

- Name: #!
- Context: Perl
- Description: Any fancy Description
- Pattern: ${cursor}#!/usr/bin/env perl

After you enabled and applied, you should be able to auto insert the shebang when you type #! then ctrl+space.

Also, you can import templates externally, there are tons online with all the basics covered. :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Eclipse - EPIC - Perl for a couple of years now. (On Windows XP SP3 and on Windows 7). I find it an excellent tool (much better than PADRE) which I had initially tried out. Its management of variable monitoring is superb.

Once in  while I encounter a little bug, but usually those are quite workable.
I'm simply not using the templates (on Windows you don't need the shebang anyway).

Comment: OK, well thats nice for you, but that doesn' really help me :) I just want my new perl files to include some stuff, that I always need... "use strict" for example. With Java I always have my little comment-section with name of the author, mail , name of the program etc etc. That should also be possible for EPIC I think